# Is there an analogue of the Kochen-Specker property in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

*Motivation*

Entanglement and entanglement measures are traditionally defined in finite-dimensional systems. Nowadays there are very well-known definitions of entanglement measures in quantum field theories.

In finite-dimensional systems, one also has a notion of *contextuality* in the sense of the [Kochen-Specker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochen%E2%80%93Specker_theorem). There are various recent work on "measures" of contextuality.

Note that one can give examples of systems that have the KS property but no entanglement.

*Question*

Is there an analogue of the Kochen-Specker property in quantum field theory?

*Subquestion & first step*:

Does it make sense to define and measure contextuality on an arbitrary square lattice?

Answer (score 1):

Contextuality is only partially related with entanglement. It concerns some  consequences of the fact that  observables exist which cannot be defined simultaneously. More precisely it is a property of every realistic  hidden variable theory which explains the same outcomes of measurements of a quantum theory. The Kochen Specker theorem is consequence of the Gleason theorem. The latter, to work,  needs nothing but a separable Hilbert space with dimension greater than two. Hence QFT is included straightforwardly.

Answer (score -1):

At the semantic level (not semantic structure of theory) of language, the concepts of contextuality should be applied and emerges on the field equation.

But is it?

I don't think so.
Before contextuality, let me remind where the contextuality came from.
After quantum entanglement, there is the quantum nonlocality which works as a strange form of the computational resource.
However, in physics, this is just combination of incompatibleness of hidden variable theory, relativity and non-determinism.
Contextuality is just a spatial concentration of nonlocality.

So I believe the nonlocality of quantum field theory must be studied first.
In a sense, nonlocality does work in qft, considering interaction range on correlated system.
Here, you might want to argue something contextual, but I believe it is hard to find such on lattice like interacting particle systems.